# FFmpeg/AVconc - Capture Seamless Video

Tags: linux, video, ffmpeg

I have several IP cams that I want to capture video from continuously.  I'm building a script that will wrap around ffmpeg to capture from the various RTSP sources.  But I'm struggling with how to capture and store the data.. specifically, how do I capture seamless clips?

To clarify, if I just run a command like this:

```
ffmpeg -i rtsp://ip_cam file.mp4
```

This is going to run forever until it fills up my hard drive (or until I hit some upper limit of ffmpeg or the filesystem).  So my thinking was to do something like this:

```
ffmpeg -i rtsp://ip_cam -fs 104857600 file-1.mp4
```

This would limit the files to 100MB each.  My wrapper script can start a new instance as soon as this one finishes:

```
ffmpeg -i rtsp://ip_cam -fs 104857600 file-2.mp4
```

And so on (I can have a separate process that will make sure to clear out the old files as needed to recover space).  The problem with this approach is that it takes 1-2 seconds for ffmpeg to start, *which means during that time the camera in question isn't recording anything*.

One additional thing to consider is that for each file, I need to know the start and stop timestamp, for instance, `file-1.mp4` may refer to "2015-09-12 09:03:42" through "2015-09-12 11:24:21".  This way, if a user wants to retrieve a specific clip, I know where to get it.  And if I'm starting ffmpeg for each clip, and then it ends at the end of each clip, I can capture and store that information.  But if a suggested approach is to tell ffmpeg to run indefinitely while saving the output in separate chunks (if ffmpeg can do that), that may not work since I won't be able to collect this information.

Any insight would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the [segment muxer](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#segment_002c-stream_005fsegment_002c-ssegment).

```
ffmpeg -i rtsp://ip_cam -c copy -f segment -segment_list out.list -segment_time 900 \
-segment_atclocktime 1 -strftime 1 "%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S.mkv"
```

- `-segment_list` Generate a list file.
- `-segment_time` Set segment duration. The value must be a duration specification. Default value is 2. Note that splitting may not be accurate, unless you force the reference stream key-frames at the given time. See the [segment muxer documentation](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#segment_002c-stream_005fsegment_002c-ssegment) for more info.
- `-segment_atclocktime` If set to "1" split at regular clock time intervals starting from 00:00 o’clock. The time value specified in `-segment_time` is used for setting the length of the splitting interval. For example, with segment_time set to "900", this makes it possible to create files at 12:00 o’clock, 12:15, 12:30, etc.
- `-strftime` This allows segments to be named by time of file creation.

Example output file names:

```
$ ls -m1
2015-09-12_14-10-02.mkv
2015-09-12_14-10-14.mkv
2015-09-12_14-10-24.mkv
2015-09-12_14-10-34.mkv
2015-09-12_14-10-44.mkv
2015-09-12_14-10-54.mkv
```

See the [docs](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#segment_002c-stream_005fsegment_002c-ssegment) for lots more options and info.

Comment: This looks like it might be a viable option. I'm not able to get `-strftime` to work, may not be compatible with my version, it says that it's unrecognized, but I can address that later. The rest of the command works, but it doesn't segment the file the way I think it should. I have a 43-minute file, and I'm using `-segment_time 10`, which I would assume would give me a bunch of 10-second files, but I get a file that is the same as the input file. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: @NickCoons You should update your question with your `ffmpeg` command and the complete console output.

Comment: While updating my answer with the requested information, I figured out the answer. I don't have the cameras handy, so I was using a local file as input for testing. It appears that it doesn't work the way I think it does.. it doesn't break the file into 10-second segments, rather, it processes for 10 seconds then creates another file. My test failed because it takes about 5 seconds to process my input file. When I shorten the length to 2 seconds, it does work. I think I'll have better luck with the camera in hand, so it looks like your solution will work.

Comment: @NickCoons You can simulate a live stream with the `-re` input option. The complete console output will still be useful.